# How to sort JSON_EXTRACT or JSON_VALUE value in alphanumeric order in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, alphanumeric, json-value

```
SELECT * 
FROM config_server_db.configuration_item 
where configuration_item.topic_info_id = 96 AND FIND_IN_SET('6f517a22-2df5-4b75-30af-bce2bd7b066a', labels)  
order by JSON_VALUE(configuration_item.cfg_value, '$."rows"."4af8ecaf-4437-615a-7abd-937cd6883ce6"') desc;
```

If descending the row value must be sorted in alphanumeric order something like this and if it is ascending then reverse way. This is the expectation.

```
dnn16
dnn13
dnn11
dnn10
dnn9
dnn8
dnn7
dnn6
dnn3 
dnn1
```

But currently, It gets sorted in binary order, mysql natural sorting

```
dnn9
dnn8
dnn7
dnn6
dnn3
dnn16
dnn13
dnn11
dnn1
```

cfg_value is something like this

```
{
    "tableId": "6f517a22-2df5-4b75-30af-bce2bd7b066a",
    "rows": {
        "4af8ecaf-4437-615a-7abd-937cd6883ce6": "dnn9"
    }
}
```

Please note: These strings can be anywhere and anything, it could also be 1dnn,dnn1, abc123gef, abc, 123

Comment: *This is the expectation* Trim leading `'dnn'`, convert to numeric then sort. *But currently, It gets sorted in binary order, mysql natural sorting* This is common string values sorting. Alphabetical sorting.

Comment: Please note: These strings can be anything, it could also be 1dnn,dnn1, abc123gef, abc, 123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad

`ORDER BY lpad(JSON_VALUE(configuration_item.cfg_value, '$."rows"."4af8ecaf-4437-615a-7abd-937cd6883ce6"'), 10, 0)`

Assuming maximum string length is 10, you can adjust to a bigger length if you want to.